# gpg protection algorithm is not supported

Tags: encryption, redhat, public-key-encryption, gnupg

I have files that are encrypted with gpg. I've created a new server and I exported\imported the public and private key to my new server. The files are now encrypted on the new server. When I try to decrypt a file on the new server I get the following error:

gpg: protection algorithm 3 is not supported
gpg: encrypted with 4096-bit ELG key, ID 15BBEC7A, created 2012-11-21
      "test test (Logs) "
gpg: public key decryption failed: Invalid cipher algorithm
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key

If I copy the file to my old server I'm still able to decrypt it. I can't find the problem. My first guess is that the cipher used originaly is CATS5 and that it's no longuer supported.

Comment: maybe different versions of gpg on servers? try to run `gpg --version` and show result

Answer (score 1):

Yes, algorithm 3 is CAST5.  You will have to compile GnuPG yourself or use an older version.

However, it's curious that your system cannot handle CAST5.  Have you enabled FIPS mode?  That would explain it.